# android_core publish/subscribe very slow

Tags: ros, android-core, android-gingerbread, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently I am testing ROS to see if it would be worthwhile to convert some of our Android robotics code over to it. I've run into an issue where running any sort of Publisher/Subscriber as it is far too slow due to either the serialization of the messages or the number of messages being sent (I can't tell which).

Specifically, I am running an OrientationPublisher from android_gingerbread_mr1 and simply setting up a subscriber that takes the Pose and updates a text view on the screen. This slows the phone down so much and takes so many resources that attempting to press a button or anywhere on the screen for that matter, causes Android to kill the application for being unresponsive. I am currently using this phone (spec sheet in link): http://www.phonerated.com/cell-phone.php?phone=samsung+admire

Is there something I am doing wrong, or any suggestions on how to fix my issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35744/android_core-publish/subscribe-very-slow/) by [alexdicarlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2546/alexdicarlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's several demos or ROS running on Android.  You can see some of them on the [ROS blog](http://www.ros.org/cgi-bin/mt-4.3/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=1&tag=Android&limit=20)

Your problems sound more like a bug than performance issues.  I suggest that you double check your threading model.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-07-02**:
It could be both or either. Performance on Android isn't great, but has gotten much better (about an order of magnitude) in the last couple weeks. Expect more improvements to follow.